# Android Studio Electric Eel's New Logcat - How do I get only the logs I manually logged?

Tags: android, android-studio

In the old logcat all I would have to do is type my package name in the search bar.

e.g `com.dave.mynewapp`

but now when you type in the package name it constantly displays log messages EVERY SINGLE SECOND that I don't need making it hard to debug.

[image]

Also now, the cursor doesn't automatically scroll down when a new log appears making it even more frustrating

[image]

I am able to filter it by typing the activity name... e.g `MainActivity`, but it becomes very annoying to type out every single class name that I have logs in.

Is there a way to get all the logs I manually created, but ignore the clutter I have in the picture above?

**Update October 2023:**

Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
no longer spams the user with all these useless logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you can try this :

filter specify the package name `package:com.dave.mynewapp`

filter specify the Tag  `tag:MainActivity`

filter mutil tags like `package:com.dave.mynewapp tag:MainActivity tag:MainActivity2`

 detail info about this link https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

Comment: Hi, yeah that's what I said above. I could do that, but it gets annoying because I would have to do that for every class. In the old logcat, I would only need to add the package name.

Comment: Also, everytime I click "Run app" button, it would automatically switch the tab from logcat to 'app'. Very frustrating. I ended up just downgrading to the AS version with the old logcat because I don't want to deal with this.

Comment: To be honest, I also encountered very strange problems in the new version. There are always problems with multi-device switching, tags with spaces and so on. Might have to wait for it to stabilize before upgrading

Answer (score 0):

I had luck by filtering on: tag:info

var tag = "info"

Log.i(tag, "Names: $names")